# MongooseJS - Model.create with existing ref

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use the `model.create()` shorthand to create a new Company with an **existing** User ObjectId.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});

const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: String,
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('user2', userSchema);
const Company = mongoose.model('company2', userSchema);
```

The following user already exists in the `users` collection

```
{"_id":"5a9633031fe445041c07afd3","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","__v":0}
```

Now I want to create a new company with this existing user:

```
Company.create({
  companyName: 'Foo, Inc.',
  users: {5a9633031fe445041c07afd3}
}).then(function(err, company) {
  console.log(err, company);
});
```

I've tried variations of the user as:

```
users: '5a9633031fe445041c07afd3'
users: [5a9633031fe445041c07afd3]
users: [{5a9633031fe445041c07afd3}]
```

How can I save this document?

Comment: `User.get(userid)` ?

Comment: OMG, so much wasted time on a typo: `const Company = mongoose.model('company2', userSchema);` should have been `const Company = mongoose.model('company2', companySchema);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let model = new Company();
const body = {
    companyName: 'Foo, Inc.',
    users: "5a9633031fe445041c07afd3"
};
model = Object.assign(model, body);
model.then((company) => {
    console.log(company);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```